# Why is there an error saying that the object is not found?

Tags: r

The following link displays an image of the coding that I have done:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChZFl.png]

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Regarding your error: there is no object named `Height`. `Height` is part of `my_data`, therefore access it by `my_data$Height`. But first assign your transformed data.frame to `my_data`.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for hints for questions.

Comment: As well as [mcve]. Thank you! :)

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience. I will ask the question according to the format for future problems. Thank you for you response

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference the table you are using, so instead of

```
hist(Age)
```

use

```
hist(my_data$Age)
```

Comment: Please vote up if my answer helped you :)

Comment: user13655174 can't vote up yet. You need 15 reputation.